# How do I make three divs within a lightning layout item evenly space out to take up the entirety of the available space?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

How do I make my three divs within this lightning layout item evenly space with the logo at the absolute top of the layout item and the button at the absolute bottom?

Right now the text displays right under the logo and the button displays right under the text leaving empty space beneath. I don't really want to use padding, I would prefer something more dynamic.

```
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" class="lightningLayout slds-grid_align-space" vertical-align="stretch" flexibility="auto, no-shrink">
        <template for:each={services} for:item="service" for:index="index">
            <lightning-layout-item size="3" key={service.Id} class={service.Class}>
                <div>
                    <img alt={service.Title} src={service.Logo} class="slds-align_absolute-center"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <lightning-formatted-text value={service.Body} class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-align_center textBody"></lightning-formatted-text>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={service.ButtonText} title={service.ButtonText} onclick={handleTileClick} class="slds-button slds-align_absolute-center"></lightning-button>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Comment: It'd help if you could add a screenshot of what you're seeing now and a mockup of what you'd like to see. Feel free to [edit] your question, then let me know, and I'll be happy to take a look at it for you.